# FullCalendar and JQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar-4

I made a Fullcalendar in my Laravel app. The render is exactly what I want : a calendar on the left and when users clic on a day, this day become "red", and the list of hours for meetings is create on the right.

See the result here (I have just blur the coach name ;) :

[image: Calendar]

I create the list with this code in my calendar :

```
dateClick: function (info) {
            //Colorize the select day in red
            $('*').removeClass('activeday');
            $('[data-date=' + info.dateStr + ']').addClass('activeday');

            // Ajax for recover all events 'Disponible"
            let qlq;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'events/get-disponibility',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                data: {
                    date: info.dateStr,
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    qlq = data;
                }
            });

            let html = "<h3>Horaires et Coachs disponibles : </h3> <br>";
            if (qlq.length) {
                qlq.forEach(function (row) {
                    html = html + '<div class="container d-flex mb-3">\
                    <div class="col-6">\
                    <span id="puce">&#8226;</span>\
                        ' + row.admin_prenom + ' ' + row.admin_nom + ' </div> \
                    <div class="col-6 justify-content-around">\
                        <span class="badge badge-pink">' + row.start_date.substring(11, 16) + '</span>\
                        <a href="#' + row.id + '" class="get-modal-event"\
                         data-idEvent=' + row.id + '>\
                        <span class="badge badge-dark">\
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>\
                        </span>\
                        </a>\
                    </div>\
                </div>';
                });

                $("#freeCoach").empty()
                    .append(html);
            } else {
                $("#freeCoach").empty()
                    .append('<div class="container d-flex mb-3">\
                    <div class="col-12">\
                    <span id="puce">&#8226;</span>\
                        Pas de coach disponible à cette date. <br>\
                        <br>\
                         Seul les dates comportant un fond coloré comporte des disponibilités</div> \
                </div>');
            }
        },
```

Now I just want to popup a bootstrap modal, when users click on the black arrow (a link whith the class "get-modal-event").

So I use, after my calendar render, this JQuery code :

```
$('a.get-modal-event').each(() => {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('get modal !!!!!');
            $('#modal-event').modal('show');
        })
```

I have create an alert box to see that function work, but no alert is showing and no modal appears...

I tried to create a link outside of the calendar (with is own class for a test) and both alert and modal appear !

I also tried to put this code in a different file and build it, but the result is the same.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click()` binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that *already exist*. It won't get bound for dynamically created elements. you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using [**`on()`**].

Here you'll need to use:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.get-modal-event', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('get modal !!!!!');
   $('#modal-event').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it doesn't work either. But i undestand your point with "direct" binding.

Comment: @Malkom I think you don't need to add "each" loop above click event. Just tried it with $('body').on('click', 'a.get-modal-event', function(e) {}); I believe that should work.